# Which cases allow forward referencing in static initializer blocks?

Tags: java, class, static, initialization, declaration

In Java, initialization of static variables is executed in textual order. As a result it's not possible to access a static variable e.g. in a static initializer block before it is decleared.

However, I noticed that there are certain possibilities to access a static variable before it is declared.

Given the following code:

```java
static {
    STATIC = true;
}
public static boolean STATIC = false;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(STATIC);
}
```

One would expect that there is a compile error in the static initializer block (`STATIC = true;`), but it's actually compiling fine. Furthermore, the output of the program is `false`. I'd expect it to be `true`, since I'm assigning a value to it in the static initializer.

- Why is this code snippet not a compile error and why is the variable not set to `true` after initialization?
- In which cases (in general) is it possible to forward access a static variable in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why is this code snippet not a compile error and why is the variable not set to true after initialization?

Java allows forward references to static variables if it is used on the left hand side of an assignment statement. The reason why the value is `false` after initialization is, that when Java reaches the static initializer block, the variable `STATIC` is already declared (which happens before actual initialization of the class) and initially set to `false` (default value). After the static initializer, the assignment on the declaration line is still executed and the value will end up as `false`.

### In which cases (in general) is it possible to forward access a static variable in Java?

The Java Language Specification (JLS) for Java 8 says in [12.4.1 When Initialization Occurs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> The *static initializers* and *class variable initializers* are
>   **executed in textual order**, and **may not refer to class variables**
>   declared in the class whose **declarations appear
>   textually after the use**, even though these class variables are in
>   scope (§8.3.3).

In general, as stated, forward references are not allowed. But there are certain exceptions described in [8.3.3 Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3):

> **8.3.3. Forward References During Field Initialization**
>
> Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually
>   after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these class
>   variables are in scope (§6.3). Specifically, it is a compile-time
>   error **if all of the following are true**:
>
> - The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C
>     appears textually after a use of the class variable
> - The use
>     is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C or a
>     static initializer of C
> - The use is not on the left hand side
>     of an assignment
> - C is the innermost class or interface
>     enclosing the use

To illustrate these conditions, I created the class `ThisClass` with an example for each of the conditions. If only one of those four conditions is false, it's not a compile error!

---

**1. The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the class variable**

```java
public static boolean STATIC1 = false;
static {
    if (!STATIC1) {
        System.out.println("Set STATIC1 to true");
        STATIC1 = true;
    }
}
```

The usage of `STATIC1` occurs after it is defined. The most basic condition for a compiler error is violated. As you would expect, the value of `STATIC1` after initialization is `true`.

---

**2. The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C or a static initializer of C**

```java
static {
    if (!ThisClass.STATIC2) {
        System.out.println("Set STATIC2 to true");
        ThisClass.STATIC2 = true;
    }
}
public static boolean STATIC2 = false;
```

The first condition is now met, but the second condition is violated. We are using the *qualified name* (and not the *simple name*) to access the variable `STATIC2`. The difference is described in the JLS in [6.2 Names and Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2):

> There are two forms of names: simple names and qualified names.
>  A
>   *simple name* is a single identifier.
>  A *qualified name*
>   consists of a name, a "." token, and an identifier.

More interesting is, what actually happens during initialization. On the first line of the static initializer, the value of `STATIC2` is read via the class qualifier. At this point (since the class is initialized in textual order) the variable `STATIC2` has not been initialized yet. In this case, the default value is used, which for `boolean` is `false`. The `if` block is entered and the value of `STATIC2` is set to `true`. Initialization is continued and `STATIC2` is set to `false` again, which is the state the variable will be in after initialization.

*Note:* To prove that the assignment to `true` actually happens, you can try something like this:

```java
static {
    if (!ThisClass.STATIC2a) {
        System.out.println("Set STATIC2a to true");
        ThisClass.STATIC2a = true;
    }
}
public static boolean STATIC2a;
```

This code compiles perfectly fine and the value of `STATIC2a` at the end of initialization will be `true`! The last line of code can even be replaced with the following curious statement, which clarifies even more what's happening:

```java
public static boolean STATIC2a = ThisClass.STATIC2a;
```

---

**3. The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment**

```java
static {
    System.out.println("Set STATIC3 to true");
    STATIC3 = true;
}
public static boolean STATIC3 = false;
```

Now we are using the class variable before declaration and are using it with a simple name. However, the third condition in the JLS is not met, since it appears on the left hand side of an assignment. What happens is more or less the same as if it was accessed qualified. The default value `false` of `STATIC3` is overridden with `true` and then set back to false on the last line of code.

*Note:* The same as in example 2a holds true. If there is no assignment on the last line of code (or the `STATIC3a = ThisClass.STATIC3a` no-op), `STATIC3a` is initialized to `true`:

```java
static {
    System.out.println("Set STATIC3a to true");
    STATIC3a = true;
}
public static boolean STATIC3a;
```

---

**4. C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use**

```java
static class OtherClass {
    static {
        if (!STATIC4) {
            System.out.println("Set STATIC4 to true");
            STATIC4 = true;
        }
    }
}
public static boolean STATIC4 = false;
```

`STATIC4` is defined in the outer class `ThisClass` and therefor not defined in the innermost class from the perspective of use in `OtherClass`. The first line in the static block meets all three above conditions. Declaration appears textually after the use, it's referenced by a simple name and the use is also not on the left hand side of an assignment. But since outer classes are always initialized before any nested class, the `STATIC4 = false` assignment in `ThisClass` happens before the static initializer in `OtherClass`.

It is important to see, that initialization of `OtherClass` does not have to happen when the outer `ThisClass` is initialized (it might even be loaded, but loading != initialization). We need to make sure, that `OtherClass` is initialized by e.g. creating an instance of it (see [12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) in the JLS).

---

The whole program can be studied here:
http://ideone.com/fl5Vet

Comment: Good explanation, but I still don't understand what's the point to restrict simple names and accept qualified names?
Maybe it's like type casing: to indicate explicitly what your code does.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason as well. Your explanation sounds reasonable. It could be a kind of intended fail-safe to prevent accidental forward references which would be overridden by the lowermost statement.

Comment: There is another interesting moment about forward reference by qualified name: reference to a static variable returns default value (0, false, null or \u0000), but reference to a static final variable (constant) returns actual value (which is like a normal reference).

Comment: That is because constants are initialized in an earlier phase than the static class variables. At the moment when the static initializer runs with a forward reference, the class variable hasn't been initialized and therefor the default value is used. That's also why `!ThisClass.STATIC2` in example 2 is always `false`, even if initialization on the last line would be to `true`.